# Multiple web service calls from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first JavaScript Chrome Extension using JQuery 2.2.0, which basically takes the current URL and polls a few different web services to see if they have a record of the URL. If it exists, I add a text link in the DOM. Here's a simplified working version:

```
// Does the provided URL exist?
function url_exists(url) {
    var h = new XMLHttpRequest();
    h.open('HEAD', url, false);
    h.send();
    return h.status!=404;
}

// Display a link to the database record URL in the DOM
function display_database_link(url) {
  $('body').prepend('<a href="' + url + '">Link</a>');
}


// Get the current URL
var url             = window.location.href;
var database_number = 0;

// See if this URL exists in one of our databases via the API

// Does the URL exist in database 1?
if (url_exists("https://api.database1.com/urls/" + url)) {
  database_number = 1;
}

// Does the URL exist in database 2?
else if (url_exists("https://api.database2.com/urls/" + url)) {
  database_number = 2;
}

if (database_number > 0) {
  display_database_link("https://api.database" +  database_number + ".com/urls/" + url))
}
```

What I have works, but I'm wondering if:

1. there's a way to make multiple calls to url_exists at once, and
2. if there's a way to do this asynchronously.

If someone could respond with a link to relevant documentation or examples, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: If you're using Jquery anyways, why `XMLHttpRequest`? Just use `$.ajax` and callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of awesome es2015 features that will make this nice and easy: [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) and [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises/). You'll have to do some tweaking but something like this should work.

```
// Array of API endpoints to to make requests to
let url = window.location.href;
let database_urls = ["https://api.database1.com/urls/", "https://api.database2.com/urls/"];

// Promise.all will take an array of promises and perform all of them, and `then` process all results at the end
Promise.all(database_urls.map(database_url =>
  // Make an HTTP request to the endpoint, and `then` get the status code from the response
  fetch(database_url + url).then(response => response.status)
// Once `all` promises are resolved, `then` iterate over the resulting statuses
)).then(statuses => {
  // Reduce `statuses` to a count of how many are not 404s
  let existCount = statuses.reduce((prev, curr) => {return curr == 404 ? prev : prev + 1}, 0);
  // Call method to display link if existsCount is > 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can make all of them at once, the browser will execute them at once but the results will take diferente amounts of time to reach you...
2. You have: `h.open('HEAD', url, false);` the third parameter (`false`) defines if the request is asynchronous or synchronous.... It should be set to true: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
3. Since you have jQuery why not use the AJax function? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
4. Be careful, if your extension is making 1000 requests to 1000 databases it will slow down the user browser/internet.
5. This requests take X amount of time until you get a response back, so don't immediately check if `database_number` is greater than 0.